# DateTimePicker.selectedDate different than DateTimePicker.Text

Tags: c#, wpf, datetimepicker

I have a dateTimePicker. In order to write this DateTimePicker content to my DataBase, i get the value with :

```
myDateTimePicker.selectedDate.value.
```

It's ok when the user selected manually the date.

But...when the user type the date directly in the DateTimePicker, the `SelectedDate.value` give me the older value. The good value, is in the `.Text` property.

Is there a way to synchronize the `.Text` with the `.SelectedValue.value` ?

Maybe I need to read an other property ?

Comment: Why cant you use the `.text` property?

Comment: because i need to store it, in a DateTime variable ! Not in a string !

Comment: `DateTime yourDate = (DateTime)myDateTimePicker.Text;`  you could get around your problem by just converting the text to a date time variable.  Or use the `.Value` property.

Comment: Cannot convert string to DateTime ! ( by a cast !) In addition, i don't have a .Value property !

Comment: Just use Convert.ToDateTime(myDateTimePicker.Text);

Comment: I found the problem ! If i select a date, the "SelectedDate" is ok ! If i type a date, the selectedDate is not OK ! If i type a date and if i leave the field ( with tabulation), the SelectedDate is ok ! So, is there a way to synchronize it always ?

Comment: When do you use `myDateTimePicker.selectedDate.value`? Do you have a routed event with a button? Could you possibly provide your code?

Comment: Yes I think an event like ValueChanged might solve this problem.

Comment: Why are you picking up the date before the users leaves the DatePicker?  How can you know they are done entering the date?

Comment: This probably also surfaces if you programmatically set the Value, eg prior to showing the form, of as part of date range validation. Even setting myDtp.Text = myDtp.Value.ToString() doesn't work. Buggy!

Answer (score 2):

This happens because validation is only performed when a control loses focus. Normally controls like this are on dialog boxes (i.e. ShowDialog), and the dialog box is completed by activating an OK button (directly or indirectly through the AcceptButton property). This causes the control to lose focus and validate itself.

If you're using the DateTimePicker on a modeless window, you'll want to remove focus from it before using its selected value so that it performs validation.

Answer (score 1):

One can use these conversions in the code for runtime processing. "on change" methods can be used too but this is the quickest way. They can even be used in those methods too.

date to text conversion

```
setdate.Text = setdate.SelectedDate.ToString();
```

text to date conversion (if the format is acceptable)

```
setdate.SelectedDate = DateTime.Parse(setdate.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DateTimePicker](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=DateTimePicker&referringTitle=Home) from Extended WPF Toolkit.

There is property `Value` and when you start typing in the text box of this control  entered value will be automaticly assigned to your binding property.

Example:

XAML:

```
<extToolkit:DateTimePicker Value="{Binding MyDate, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

where "extToolkit" is:

```
xmlns:extToolkit="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
```

ViewModel class:

```
class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private DateTime _myDate;

    public DateTime MyDate
    {
        get { return _myDate; }
        set 
        { 
            _myDate = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged("MyDate"); 
            // only for testing...
            Console.WriteLine("value: " + value);
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```